# Method which does boolean check as generic

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a global static methodh which accept generic and does some boolean check and then applies my change. The idea is to make it like this:

```
public static <T> T booleanCheck(final T val, final BooleanSupplier booleanSupplier, final Supplier<T> supplier)
    {
        if (booleanSupplier.getAsBoolean())
        {
            return supplier.get();
        }

        return val;
    }
```

But i don't know how to make it. Basically i want 2 parameter. One to be the boolean and accept any object check and one that does what i want. Example:

```
final String text= "test";

final String newText = booleanCheck(!test.isEmpty(), s -> s.subString(1));
```

and will print `tes`.
Something like this but for all objects.

Comment: `final boolean val`? Or do you want to test the condition lazily? If so `final BooleanSupplier valSupplier`

Comment: What you mean??

Comment: That is the type that the `val` argument needs to be to work as you have described.  But there is a big problem.  What value is your `booleanCheck` supposed to return when the check fails?  And what  is it applying your `change` function to?

Comment: You could receive a predicate instead of `T val`

Comment: Well yes ... the OP could ... but that is not what the OP has shown us in the example usage.  That shows the method being called with the *result* of the predicate.  OP: the real problem is that your question is unclear.  You need to be a lot more precise about how you want this `booleanCheck` to behave.

Comment: I used a BooleanSupplier but the problem is the final Supplier<T> supplier now. How i can make the last part where i do  s -> s.subString(1); it doesn't work.

Comment: Well ... I think it is not working ... because you haven't actually figured out what it *should* do.  Certainly you haven't explained it to us in a way that makes sense ...

Comment: If you immediately call `booleanSupplier.getAsBoolean()`, why not just pass in a boolean?

Comment: Im sorry Stephen, basically i want a method using generic parameter which i do a check and then i use a predicate type to apply changes on the object i added. Basically it has 3 parameters. 1 the object of any type i give, 2 the boolean check of that object, 3 the part where i do change on that object and the method return.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use a `Predicate<T>` and a `UnaryOperator<T>`:

```
public static <T> T booleanCheck(
        final T value,
        final Predicate<T> predicate,
        final UnaryOperator<T> operator) {
    return predicate.test(value)
            ? operator.apply(value)
            : value;
}
```

And then call:

```
final String newValue = booleanCheck(
        oldValue,
        Predicate.not(String::isEmpty),
        s -> s.substring(1));
```

or

```
final String newValue = booleanCheck(
        oldValue,
        s -> !s.isEmpty(),
        s -> s.substring(1));
```

But as long as you are not reusing or combining predicates and operators, you are better off simply using the conditional operator:

```
final String newValue = !oldValue.isEmpty()
        ? oldValue.substring(1)
        : oldValue;
```

Answer (score 2):

Pass object as one of parameters:

```
public static <T> T booleanCheck(final T val, 
                                 final Predicate<T> predicate, 
                                 final UnaryOperator<T> operator){
    if (predicate.test(val))
      return operator.apply(val);
    return val;
}

final String text= "test";
final String newText = booleanCheck(text, s -> !s.isEmpty(), s -> s.substring(1));
```